# Is the function $|x-y|^2$ a metric in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to determine whether the function $|x-y|^2$ is a metric in $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt is as follows.

First of all it's clear it's positive, symmetric and $$|x-y|^2=0 \implies x=y$$

So I need to check if it satisfies the triangle inequality.

I have $$|x-y|^2 =|x-z|^2+|z-y|^2-2|x-z||z-y|\cos \phi $$ by the law of cosines where $\phi$ is the angle between $|x-z|$ and $|z-y|$.

But since the cosine is not always positive I will have that $$|x-y|^2 =|x-z|^2+|z-y|^2-2|x-z||z-y|\cos \phi  \leq |x-z|^2 +|z-y|^2$$ only when the cosine is positive, this will not hold for values where the cosine is negative, therefore the triangle inequality cannot be satisfied.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Your assertions are not false and the logic seems sound. You may or may not be interested in the fact that $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi$ are the only existing cases. Anyways, this is true in all $\Bbb R^n$, so there is an argument for your choice of notation.

Comment: Might be easier to consider a counterexample for the triangle inequality. E.g. $x=1,y=-1,z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $\cos$ here. Also, the angles are always $0$ or $\pi$ so it might be a bit confusing to proceed with that approach.

Instead... just check algebraically if for any $x,y,z$ we have $$(x-y)^2 \le (x-z)^2 + (y-z)^2 \tag{1}$$

This is equivalent to

$z^2-xz-yz+xy \ge 0$

Now we ask ourselves if this is true for any $x,y,z$

View this as a quadratic function of $z$

$f(z) = z^2-xz-yz+xy$
which btw is just $(z-x)(z-y)$

We find two roots for $z$ (e.g. by calculating the discriminant):

$$z_{1,2} = \frac{x+y\pm |x-y|}{2} \tag{2}$$

i.e.

$$z_{1} = x$$
$$z_{2} = y$$

So it has two real roots (for $z$).
Between these roots $f(z)$ is negative.

So let us pick for example:

x=2, y=4, z=3

Then the inequality $(2)$ (and consequently $(1)$) is not true.

So to make $(1)$ false we can pick any $x \ne y$ which are different, and pick $z$ between them.

Therefore the conclusion is that this is not a metric.